# Azure B2C Not Getting All Supported Claims

Tags: asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, owin, openid-connect, azure-ad-b2c

I have integrated my application with Azure B2C . I am able to sign in and come back to my application but I am not getting all supported claims . Below is my code

app.SetDefaultSignInAsAuthenticationType(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationType);

> ```
> app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
>         {
>             CookieSecure = CookieSecureOption.Always
>         });
>
>         app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(
>             new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
>             {
>                 MetadataAddress = String.Format(AadInstance, Tenant, DefaultPolicy),
>                 ClientId = ClientId,
>                 RedirectUri = RedirectUri,
>                 PostLogoutRedirectUri = RedirectUri,
>                 Authority=Authority,
>
>                 Notifications = new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationNotifications
>                 {
>                     RedirectToIdentityProvider = OnRedirectToIdentityProvider
>
>                 },
>                 TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
>                 {
>                     NameClaimType = "name"
>                 },
>                 Scope = "openid profile offline_access"
>             }
>         );
>     }
> ```

```
@foreach (Claim claim in ClaimsPrincipal.Current.Claims)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="claim-type claim-data">@claim.Type</td>
            <td class="claim-data">@claim.Value</td>
        </tr>
    }
```

Not sure what wrong I am doing here .The above code has been copied from azure sample mention here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/active-directory-b2c/active-directory-b2c-devquickstarts-web-dotnet-susi with some changes .

Currently I am getting only one field that is Given Name . Please suggest How I can fix this ?

Comment: did you get an answer. We are also having a similar problem

Comment: Yes , As we are using sitecore ,sitecore runs it's own security model and replaces claims . So the claims needs to be retrieved from the authentication cookie .You can check this link for more information and code sample http://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-add-federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-owin/

Answer (score 1):

I got my root cause and solution by following this

http://blog.baslijten.com/how-to-add-federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-owin/ Well explained here

Answer (score 0):

> I am able to sign in and come back to my application but I am not
>   getting all supported claims

What do you mean by this? The claims you added in Portal against policy (Application claims) are not returning or?

**B2C return claim only if the claim has value in it. If login user has values for only a few claims then those only return from policy**

Comment: I had values for all claims in B2C . But I am getting only "Given Name" not others where as they have value . Is there something from code we need to manage ?

Comment: Did you configure the policy to return those claims? Check Policies -> Choose Policy -> Edit -> Application Claims

Comment: Yes they are configured . I am getting only "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/05/identity/claims/name" this claim type

Comment: Add Application (Applications -> Add) with redirect URI as https://jwt.io and do Run Now from the portal by choosing the policy and application and redirect URI (jwt.io). Verify the claims from the jwt.io page.

Comment: In Jwt.Io I am getting all required claims .B2C is returning all . Something is missing in my application . I will check if I am missing any require package to preserver the claims .Thank You for your help . As I am building this on top of sitecore I think something is going wrong here

Comment: cooI.. I can help you out if you push sample app on git

Comment: When I debuged OnAuthorizationCodeReceived callback function I am able to see all my claims under "notification.JwtSecurityToken.Claims" and "notification.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.Claims" . So I am getting all my claims but some how it's not getting persisted to cookies . Any thought what I can do here ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149157/discussion-between-deb-and-ramakrishna).